# how would one embed an api endpoint return text result without javascript?

Tags: html, css, api, frontend, embed

hihi

basically, lets say i have

`GET /api`

and it returns something like

`8371`

now the problem is that how to embed it, currently i just make it return an svg but
itd be nice to make the api return pure data lol and iframes arent rlly an option either as theyre not fun to style or anything, so im stuck, is there a way to just embed it ? ive tried both `iframe`s and `embed`s, both sucked tbfh, i want to just embed text if possible, or at least something similar

thx for the help xx

as asked, code ( example ) :

```py
from flask import Flask, Response


app: Flask = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/api")
def api() -> Response:
    count: str = "28731"

    svg_width: int = len(count) * 14

    return Response(
        f'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{svg_width}" height="20"><text x="{svg_width / 2}" y="20" font-size="20px" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif">{count}</text></svg>',
        mimetype="image/svg+xml",
    )


app.run("127.0.0.1", 8080)
```

and

```html
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api" alt="no" />
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code you have so far - what are you doing with that svg to add it to the DOM at the moment for example?

Comment: @AHaworth here u go

Comment: what's wrong with `iframe`? you can style it inline to have width height and no border for example.

Comment: @ITgoldman bc id prefer to have text rather than an iframe